# readLine() from DataInputStream doesn't receive data correctly

Tags: java, tcp, server, client

I'm new to Socket manipulation, I'm currently doing my Java Client to communicate with my C server and I'm having a little issue with reading the data from my server.

When I launch my server, it returns correctly the whole data (I'm sending an SQL request from my Java Client, but whenever I try to read it from my client with a DataInputStream.

I'm basically trying to display usernames on the right side of my application when I launch it, sending a SQL request to the server " SELECT username FROM username WHERE status='online' ", the C server sends a response with:
"Aoisuki
AntoineLg"

When I try to read the data with readLine(); in a while loop, I'm only getting "Aoisuki" username displayed.

I don't think it is necessary to show you my C server code because I already tried with a C client and everything worked well.

So here's my Java code from the client:

```
public String recvMsg() throws IOException {
    s = new Socket(addr,port);
    din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String tmp = "";
    try {
        while(((tmp=d.readLine())!=null)){
            result.append(tmp);
            d.wait();
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
       ....
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

I already tried putting the "d.wait()" after the while loop but I was getting another issue: my Client didn't launch until the server was closed, but I had both two usernames displayed (which is what I want)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `wait` method is part of every java object. It is one part of 3 separate things that work together: the `wait` method, the `notify` method, and the `synchronized` keyword.

You should not be calling it here; there is no reason to ever call it on a bufferedreader and you shouldn't call it here. `d.readLine()` will block; you can just remove that line.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure I tried without the d.wait(), I can't tell right now as I'm not home